# How to testfor if a zombie is not in a 10 block radius of a player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Hi I was wondering since I am making an adventure map, if I could testfor a zombie not in a 10 block radius to do /stopsound

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`execute as @a at @s if entity @e[type=zombie,distance=10..] run stopsound @s * entity.zombie.ambient`

It's stopping the zombie ambient sound if the zombie is 10 blocks away. You can also stop all the other zombie sounds using the sound IDs.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to testfor a zombie not in a 10 block radius of players:

execute as @a at @s if entity @e[type=zombie,distance=..10] run stopsound...

Assuming you want to testfor a zombie not in a 10 block radius of a command block:

execute unless entity @e[type=zombie,distance=..10] run stopsound...

Comment: `positioned ~ ~ ~` does absolutely nothing. And putting a `/` after `run` is a syntax error. Haven't checked the rest.

Comment: @Fabian thanks for letting me know about the first typo, I must have typed that on accident when looking at his post. I figured the positioned thing might not work because I've never use execute without targeting an entity before. Please tell me the alternative so I can edit it.

Comment: You don't need an alternative to `positioned ~ ~ ~`, just leave it out. It does literally nothing.